# django get elements with biggest qty of content_set

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to do a reverse key query. The query is this: the foo elements that has the biggest quantity of bar.

```
Foo:
name = models.CharField('name', max_length=255)

Bar:
name = models.CharField('name', max_length=255)
foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

foo_1.name = foo1
foo_2.name = foo2
foo_3.name = foo3

bar_1.name = bar1
bar_1.foo = foo1

bar_2.name = bar2
bar_2.foo = foo2
bar_3.name = bar3
bar_3.foo = foo2

bar_4.name = bar4
bar_4.foo = foo3
bar_4.name = bar4
bar_4.foo = foo3
```

'Foo2' has 2 'bars' and 'foo3' has 2 'bars' while 'foo1' has only one 'bar'

the result i want is a list with the foos with the biggest quantity of bars and the qty of bars like this:

```
[{'foo': foo2, 'qty_of_bars': 2}, {'foo': foo3, 'qty_of_bars': 3}]
```

I've tried a lot of things, for example:

```
foos = Foo.objects.all()
foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bar = foo.annotate(bar_count=Count('bar')).order_by(
                '-bar_count').first()
```

This gives only one foo, the one with the biggest qty of bars, for example 'foo3', but there may be more than one. In the case above there are 2, foo2 and foo3.

I've tried this:

```
foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bar = foo.annotate(bar_count=Count('bar')).order_by(
        '-bar_count').first()
```

This gives me the biggest qty of bars related to one single foo

```
biggest_qty_of_bars = bars.objects.filter(foo=foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bar ).count()
foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bars = Foo.objects.all().annotate(total_bars=biggest_qty_of_bars )
```

This last line didnt work, i got:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'lookup'
```

I tried other thing with a for loop(it's terrible, very ugly, sorry guys for this, by it was an attempt on despair, it's driving me crazy):

```
qyt_of_bars_of_each_foo = Foo.object.values('name').annotate(
        count_bar=Count('bar'))

    biggest_number = 0
    foo_with_biggest_number_of_bar = []
    for qty_of_bar_of_foo in qyt_of_bars_of_each_foo :
        if qyt_of_bars_of_each_foo ['count_bar'] >= biggest_number :
            foo_with_biggest_number_of_bar .append(qty_of_bar_of_foo)
            biggest_number = qyt_of_bars_of_each_foo ['count_bar']
```

Nothing gave me the result I wanted, which is a list with the foos with the biggest quantity of bars and the qty, like I said before. I'm still trying but as I said it's driving me Crazy, i'm stuck on it since yesterday. Any help I would appreciate a lot!!

Comment: `foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bar = foo.annotate(bar_count=Count('bar')).order_by(
                '-bar_count').first()` this gives you only the first item because of the `first()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing an annotation over the entire queryset using Count and then returning the values as a list?

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.all().annotate(
    qty_of_bars=Count('bar')).order_by('-qty_of_bars').values(
    'name', 'qty_of_bars')
```

This would return a list, e.g.:

```
[{'name': u'Foo1', 'qty_of_bars': 3}, {'name': u'Foo2', 'qty_of_bars': 2}]
```

given an app module name of 'foo' and the following fixture data:

```
[{
    "fields": {
        "name": "Foo1"
    },
    "model": "foo.foo",
    "pk": 1
}, {
    "fields": {
        "name": "Foo2"
    },
    "model": "foo.foo",
    "pk": 2
}, {
    "fields": {
        "foo": 1,
        "name": "Bar1-1"
    },
    "model": "foo.bar",
    "pk": 1
}, {
    "fields": {
        "foo": 1,
        "name": "Bar2-1"
    },
    "model": "foo.bar",
    "pk": 2
}, {
    "fields": {
        "foo": 1,
        "name": "Bar3-1"
    },
    "model": "foo.bar",
    "pk": 3
}, {
    "fields": {
        "foo": 2,
        "name": "Bar1-2"
    },
    "model": "foo.bar",
    "pk": 4
}, {
    "fields": {
        "foo": 2,
        "name": "Bar2-2"
    },
    "model": "foo.bar",
    "pk": 5
}]
```

### update

If you're needing to get to values where `qt_of_bars` is greater than 1, you can easily get to those via a list comprehension, since you can't filter on an annotated field via the ORM:

```
foo_objects = [{'foo': f, 'qty_of_bars': f.qty_of_bars}
            for f in Foo.objects.all().annotate(
            qty_of_bars=Count('bar')).order_by(
            '-qty_of_bars') if f.qty_of_bars > 1]

[{'foo': <Foo: Foo1>, 'qty_of_bars': 3}, {'foo': <Foo: Foo2>, 'qty_of_bars': 2}]
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. It returned all foos, and not only foo2 and foo3. But the answer gave me an idea and I reached an answer, a bad one, but it gives the result i wanted. I did it like this:

Comment: foos_and_qty_of_bars = Foo.objets.all().annotate(qty_of_bars=Count('bar')).order_by(
        '-qty_of_bars').values('name', 'qty_of_bars')

    foos_sorted_by_qty_of_barss_first = Foo.objets.all().annotate(
        bars_count=Count('bar')).order_by(
        '-bars_count').first()

    biggest_qty_of_foos = Bar.objects.all().filter(
        foo=foos_sorted_by_qty_of_bars_first).count()

   (continue on next comment:)

Comment: foo = None
    foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bars = [foo for foo in foos_and_qty_of_bars if
                                                     foo[
                                                         'qty_of_bars'] == biggest_qty_of_bars]

    context['foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bars'] = foos_with_biggest_qty_of_bars

Comment: Helped me to have an idea, I will vote as accepted answer. If someone has a better idea please tell me.

Comment: The list in my answer was derived from real models that matched your post. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: For me it returned all foos including foo1, like this(using my example of data): [{'name': u'Foo3', 'qty_of_bars': 2}, {'name': u'Foo2', 'qty_of_bars': 2}, , {'name': u'Foo1', 'qty_of_bars': 1}]. I wanted the result to have only foo2 and foo3 because they are the foos that have more bars, they have 2, while foo1 has only one bar. The result I wanted was  [{'name': u'Foo3', 'qty_of_bars': 2}, {'name': u'Foo2', 'qty_of_bars': 2}]. It's very hard to explain, I think I didn't explain well, I hope it's more clear now. continue on next comment

Comment: There is a small diference beetween first and second result, but when there are lots of records, I must make sure the screen wont be filled with unecesserary records like foo1, which has less qty of bars than foo2 and foo3. Tell me if it makes sense to you

Comment: I see. You didn't mention needing the records where `qty_of_bars` is > 1, but you can easily accomplish that with a list comprehension. See my update for an example.

Comment: Actualy is it not exactly 'where qty_of_bars is > 1', i don't know how to explain this, but its the foo with most bars, in your example it would be only foo1, because it has 3 bars, while the other has less bars, foo2 has 2.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: My bad. Its dificult to explain. But you helped me to find a solution. Its ok.

Comment: Well, glad I could help you out in some way :)